# How to display alertdialog when an app is in background?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

This code works well but if this app is in background, alertdialog doesn't display on phone screen. It only display it on app window. I want to show alertdialog window when app works in background. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

```
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setNeutralButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
        {
        }
    });
    builder.show();
```

Comment: Do not use `AlertDialog`. Use a dialog-themed activity.

Answer (score 0):

When the app is in the background there's not much you can do except for showing a notification. As this is the recommended way to display something to your user when your app is not in focus, that's what I suggest you do.